# Cannot get the twig bridge working in laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-5, twig

So, i am giving laravel a try however i want to use twig instead of blade.

https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge

This guy wrote a "bridge" for it but i cannot get it to work.

I have added to the provider array in /config/app.php:

```
   ...
  'TwigBridge\ServiceProvider'
]
```

I've added to the aliases array in /config/app.php:

```
    'Twig' => 'TwigBridge\Facade\Twig',
],
```

But then in the readme it just shows these lines but doesn't really say where to put them:

```
Twig::addExtension('TwigBridge\Extension\Loader\Functions');
Twig::render('mytemplate', $data);
```

Without them in my routes.php file I have:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('hello.html.twig');
});
```

But all i get when i access said route is a twig error page saying

```
1 - in FileViewFinder.php line 137
2 - at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('hello.html.twig', array('/var/vhost/project101/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
3 - at FileViewFinder->find('hello.html.twig') in Factory.php line 151
```

So I can only assume I have missed something, but really don't know what.

Any laravel fans out there who managed to get twig working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.. as per usual the act of actually asking for help usually results in you mind finding the answer..

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('hello.html.twig');
    return View::make('hello', ['name' => 'younes']);
});
```

With the naming convention for the twig file being

```
<name>.twig
```

EG:
hello.twig